# fnServerData is not working

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Let me make it very simple
on server_processing.php

```
$aColumns = array('is_active','CompanyName', 'email', 'phone_no', 'web_address','id' );
$sIndexColumn = "id";
$sTable = "inf_company";
```

also set connection to db
Now the jquery function is

```
"sAjaxSource": "server_processing.php",
                "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
  // Bold the grade for all 'A' grade browsers
  if ( aData[0] != 0 )
  {
  $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html( '<input type="checkbox" name="delid[]" value="'+ aData[5] +'" />' );
  }
  if ( aData[5] != 0 )
  {
   // $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html( '<b>A</b>' ); // You can add your link here!!
 $('td:eq(5)', nRow).html( '<a href=addsubcat.php?id='+ aData[5] +'><img src="./images /edit.png" alt="edit"></a><a href="subcatList.php?del=1&id='+ aData[5] +' "><img  src="./images/del.png" alt="delete"></a>' );
   }
   return nRow;
},
                "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
aoData.push( { "name": "CompanyName",
               "value": "NATIONAL" } );

}
```

simple i want to search company name national..but it is not working

Comment: What result do you get? What is your expected result?

Comment: nothing...i want to search in table by datatable

Comment: Have you done any debugging of your own at this point? I asked because you haven't given us the source for server_processing.php, which suggests that you're confident that the problem isn't server-side. Have you actually ruled this out? The first thing I would do is use a tool like Firebug or the WebKit dev tools to see exactly what is being sent to `server_processing.php`. Is it sending what you expect? Do you see any errors in the console? What, if anything, are you getting back from the server?

Comment: all the code is working well except "fnServerData"....i want to have advance search where for search i want to pass parameters....but this is not working....

Answer (score 3):

When I checked out [`fnServerData`](http://datatables.net/ref#fnServerData) example in datatables.net, the params (i.e. *aoData*) that would be posted is assembled in [`fnServerParams`](http://datatables.net/ref#fnServerParams) instead of fnServerData itself.
So I think you should move the below:

```
"fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
    aoData.push( { "name": "as_strno",
                   "value": $('#strno').val() },
                 { "name": "as_temp_ref",
                   "value": $('#as_temp_ref').val() });
    aoData.push( { "name": "dateaddedSto",
                   "value": $('#listings_row #dateaddedSto').val() });
}
```

Comment: i tried this for simplicity to check,but it is not working...aoData.push( { "name": "id",
                   "value": '1' },
                 { "name": "as_temp_ref",
                   "value": $('#as_temp_ref').val() }); where id is the table field name in query....simply to check i want to get record having id=1..but not working

Comment: Did you check if the request (the parameters) is posted to the handler or not? Maybe you could add some debug statements to check if the request is handled successfully or not in server side. At least you have to make sure the response (json) is correct.

Comment: ReferenceError: sSource is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

$.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) {

Comment: What's your `fnServerData`? Normally, `sSource` is the first parameter of `fnServerData` function and holds the value of `sAjaxSource`.

Comment: i have changed it to fnServerParams..please check code again,,i updated